# How do I display the text in div along with applied styles in console

Tags: html, css, angular

Please find my code below

```
<div class="infills {{field.groupid}}" contentEditable="true" *ngIf="(field.fieldtype=='textarea' && field.id!='shopID' && field.isexpandable=='true')"
    id="{{field.id}}" name="{{field.id}}" [ngStyle]="{'position':'absolute','top':field.y+'px','left':field.x+'px','font-size':'12px','font-family':'Courier New','height':field.height+'px','width':field.width+'px','background':'#EEE'}"
    title="{{field.description}}" (dblclick)="openFullRTE(field.id)"></div>
```

I am using html and angular 2. I need to display the text in the above div along with the applied styles in console.

Comment: what you are trying to do ?

Comment: I need to get whatever that is typed in this div(including the styles) , process it further and then convert it to JSON.

Comment: Have changed the question. Will you be able to answer now? @PardeepJain